# Change ListView Item background color but keep the default selector style?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to programmatically set a custom background color in my ListView Adapter but I want to keep the default Listview Selector style from Android.

I am setting the background color using the "SetBacgroundResource" method of my item view.

I am using Android 4.0 and I tried the example from this blog http://daniel-codes.blogspot.co.nz/2010/07/how-to-change-listview-rows-background.html but using this example the selector shows however the unselected background color is not showing.

How can I achieve this in Android 4.0 ICS?

EDIT: Here is the Resource I am using for the List Item background drawable.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
   <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/list_item_first" /> 
</selector>
```

The code that I am using to set this background drawable is inside the GetView method of my adatapter. The code is:

```
convertView.setBackgroundResrouce(R.drawable.list_item_dark);
```

Comment: Please post the resource that you are using.

Comment: I have posted the resource to my question.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to set the property [android:drawSelectorOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3adrawSelectorOnTop) of your `ListView` to true ? 
You will be able to set a background for your item and to see the item highlighted when pressed.

Comment: Hi Yes I have already tried this... It does work however it isn't exactly the effect that I am after. I don't want the highlight to be displayed over all of the text and images in the list item.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one  :

in your Row layout set the background properties for

```
android:background="@drawable/your_selector"
```

and your `listView` set

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/your_selector"
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I am rotating the background drawables in code so the background drawable will not be the same for all of the rows therefore setting it at the listview level will not work...

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I have a custom ListView with item's background as white and on press I wanted to change it to blue color.

Answer (score 3):

Try write your custom adapter and set rowView BackgroundColor like that(if position odd number BLACK, even RED).
      also you can send a color list to adapter and set different color for every rowView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;
        enter code here

            if(rowView == null)
            {
                if((position % 2)==1){ 
                rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
                    //colorList :setBackgroundColor( colorList.get(position) )
                }
                 else{
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                }
             }           
            return rowView;
        }
```

Comment: these code can't success when i am applying some layout inflate in convertView .. so please suggest me to how to success these condition....!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply this style to your ListView:

```
<style name="List">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#CCCCCC</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

And in your xml layout this:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    style="@style/List"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"/>
```