# Puting the heart in the listView and changing heart's color by onclick

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I want to have a heart without color in the listView when I clicked on it, its color turns red and save when exit the app.

[image]

The StructAnatomy class:

```
public class StructAnatomy {

    public String title;

    //public ImageView heart_empty;

    //public boolean   done;
}
```

THe AdapterAnatomy class:

the heart_impty is an image that no color and heart_fill has color.

```
public class AdapterAnatomy extends ArrayAdapter<StructAnatomy> {

    public AdapterAnatomy(ArrayList<StructAnatomy> array) {

        super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_anatomy, array);
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {

        public ViewGroup layoutRoot;
        public TextView  txtTitle;

        //public ImageView heart_empty;

         public ViewHolder(View view) {
            layoutRoot = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutRoot);
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            //heart_empty.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_fill);
        }


        public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructAnatomy> adapter, StructAnatomy item, final int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(item.title);
            //heart_empty.setEnabled(item.done);
            layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             //******************************************************************************************
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, Anatomy1_2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                    G.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
                 }

            });
        }
     }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        StructAnatomy item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_anatomy, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code what you have done ? One way could be put heart in row.xml < xml which is used to to each row view. )

Comment: Did you even try to do this ?

Comment: yes // I explain my try

Comment: Are you using any api to get the data of like or unlike ?

Comment: Basically, you want a custom CheckBox or RadioButton. Google for that.

Answer (score 1):

- When you click on listview **getPosition**(getChildAt(position)) and
  from that you can set color
- Now on exit you need to save this to **sharedPreferences**.

---

### EX:

```
if(Your condition){    //if it is true

 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_first_image); //replace image

}else{                 

 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_second_image);

}
```

To change color of listview item you can use

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#08A3F5"));
```

Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217178/change-listview-item-background-color-but-keep-the-default-selector-style/13313051#13313051) for more detail.

Comment: I need just change the heart color by onClick on the heart_empty image.

Comment: I'm a little confused, should I check first. I'll check back later. I have two pictures of the heart that would be pasted together.

Comment: how you want this to work now ? when you click it will change color and than on exit save it to sharedpreference so when you open application it's state will be restored. it will be same as you have done while exit.

Comment: I don't want change color, I want change image (I have two image of heart, first heart has no color (gray) and second heart has red color). As shown in the photo above. I started programming fresh and I copying some codes and I'm not fluent.

Comment: Than you need to check condition, use if else and replace image as you require.

Comment: I do't understand your mean, my English is not good . I want to Favourites the user, be replaced with a red heart.

Comment: i got it. please check edited answer. check if else condition and implement accordingly. @gadolf

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of your heart on click , write

```
heartViww.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

If you want to save the color of selected heart even if exit from the app then you can save one boolean in sharedpreference and again when come back to app in your adapter constructor check that boolean from shared preference.

Comment: I need change the heart color by onClick.

Comment: So in my answer i have mentioned for set color for heart.

Answer (score 0):

I use these codes and my goal is satisfied:

```
public void heart(int heartId, int listViewId) {
    final String NameId = listViewId + "";
    final ImageView heart = (ImageView) findViewById(heartId);

    if (AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getClicked(NameId).equals("1")) {
        heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_fill);
    } else {
        heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_empty);
    }

    heart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {

            if (AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getClicked(NameId).equals("1")) {
                heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_empty);
                AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setClicked(NameId, "0");
            } else {
                heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_fill);
                AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setClicked(NameId, "1");
            }

        }
    });
}
```